# PHP symfony www.one.com hosting

Tags: php, symfony

I have a working symfony project on my linux computer.

I'm trying to set it up with hosting www.one.com

I wrote a .htaccess file but I'm getting the following error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot declare interface Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface, because the name is already in use in /customers/x/x/x/xxxxxxxxxx.be/httpd.www/var/cache/dev/classes.php on line 6397
```

Can anyone help me in the write direction?

ps:

I followed the guide http://trac.symfony-project.org/wiki/InstallingSymfonyOnOne but it does not seems to be working.

Comment: I read the threat. I already did cache:clear --env=prod, this does not help.

Answer (score 1):

A guide which you are following is about `Symfony 1.x`, interface you mention is from `Symfony 2` so you have a mismatch here. Try to follow [this](https://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment.html) guide (and remember that Symfony 1.x and 2.x/3.x has nothing in common).

And just a guess: try to clear the cache on your new machine:

`app/console cache:clear --env=prod`

Comment: I already did cache:clear --env=prod, this does not help